# Remove subarray from a 2d array based on their existence in another 2d array (return a new 2d array)

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2d array, A and B, like the following.

```
A=array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9]])
B=array([[1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 8]])
```

I want to remove subarrays of A if they exist in B. Then return a new 2d array C like the following:

```
C=array([[2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

Currently I have tried the np.isin function but the result is no longer a 2d array.

```
mask = np.isin(A, B, invert=True)
A[mask]
>>array([2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the booleans on axis 1:

```
C = A[~np.isin(A,B).all(1)]
```

output:

```
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `in1d`:

```
C = A[~np.in1d(A, B).all(axis=1)]
```

And now:

```
print(C)
```

Output:

```
[[2 2 2]
 [4 4 4]
 [5 5 5]
 [6 6 6]
 [7 7 7]
 [9 9 9]]
```

Comment: This is incorrect, that would match only the first column

Comment: @mozway Edited mine

Comment: `numpy.in1d` is semi-deprecated. From the docs: *We recommend using :func:`isin` instead of `in1d` for new code.* ;)